# UIScrollView with paging in monotouch

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I found this article about UIScrollView with paging:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/45818/UIScrollView-with-paging-sample-for-Monotouch-Deve

The writer said that:

> ".... Insert 3 view controllers and make outlets like _page1, _page2, _mainpage.. 
>             and link these outlets with views. note you must referance to 
>             view controller's view outlet with _mainpage view."

I'm new in monotouch and this article have not any source code that I used it to get similar with it. Can any body help me what the above sentence meaning and what I should to do this ?

Comment: Really I just found the mentioned article in web for monotouch. if any body knows another article I hope be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy tutorial available which uses https://github.com/escoz/monotouch-controls - it doesn't use XIBs, it's well written, very small and has full code on GitHub:

http://escoz.com/blog/paging-controllers-with-monotouch/